# first boot, login with ssh, only default user, no keyboard

Tags: boot, pi-3b+

I freshly installed `Raspbian` on my new Model 3 B. My Pi has an external touch display, which works, but I have no USB keyboard. Therefore I'd like to connect with my Pi via `ssh` to set it up and configure it.
But after/during first booting the Pi, I need to type in a user name, only there's no screen keyboard on the display shown. I also cannot connect via `ssh` (look at the end of the post).

So I'd like to manually set up a user to be able to connect with `ssh` to the Raspberry.

```bash
$ ssh pi@192.168.1.9
Please note that SSH may not work until a valid user has been set up.

See http://rptl.io/newuser for details.
pi@192.168.1.9's password:  
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.9's password:  
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.9's password:  
pi@192.168.1.9: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: Check out the [Advanced settings section of the Raspberry Pi Imager Guide](https://raspberrytips.com/raspberry-pi-imager-guide/). There you can se up your username `Nepumuk` and password, and copy the public key for ssh.

Comment: (Beside the link in the answer of the question in the duplicate notice) I also managed booting and logging in remotely by following the `Headless setup` from https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022.